# change checkbox checked via session variable

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, session, checkbox

I have a form with checkboxes which are used to select data from mysql. I also would like to have the checkboxes to stay checked if the user has done so. In addition to that, those checkboxes are generated from a mysql select. Each user has different checkboxes based on their permission levels etc.

So I got this code working:

```
<form method="post" id="someselect">
    <?php

    function checked() {
        if (in_array("somestring", $_SESSION['specificvalue'])) {
            return "checked";
        };
    }

    $i = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<input id='specificvalue' type='checkbox' " . checked() . " name='specificvalue[]'  value='" . $row['specificvalue'] . "'>" . $row['longvalue'] . "<br>";
    };

    mysqli_close($con);

    //$_SESSION['specificvalue']=implode("','",$specificvalue);
    $_SESSION['specificvalue'] = $specificvalue;
    ?>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

It works, generates user specific checkboxes and the `function checked()` also works with the `exeption that` instead `in_array("somestring", $_SESSION['subunit'])` , I would like to use `in_array($row['subunit'], $_SESSION['subunit'])`, which simply does not work. I am to noob to understand why or come up with a better solution. The point of this would be to generate checkbox list and already check the boxes that have been stored in session variable before.

At the moment, with this working code. If I have the list of checkboxes and I check the box with `specificvalue` "somestring", all the checkboxes will be checked when the checkbox form is generated.

I think I would be able to use jquery for that but google gives me different kinds of solutions which cannot be used in mine. I also cannot manually write the checkboxes because there are ca 70 of them all together and they vary in time. I would like to get them autopopulated when the mysql database is updated.

Comment: no. there are bunch of includes on this that id not include in this question. The session and all the variables work just fine. the only question is how to preserve the checked values correctly via each checkbox line generated with while loop

Comment: session is already started

Comment: almost, instead of checked = 'checked' i put just checked. It seems to work but doesn't exactly keep all the checked boxes checked

Comment: and i figured it out. at first it shows me the values from post and the second time from session variable. anyway i think this pointed me to the right direction, so thanks

Comment: niceone, somebody gave some suggestions and then deleted them. now i'm talking with myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you can't use `in_array($row['subunit'], $_SESSION['subunit'])` in your function is that `$row['subunit']` doesn't exist in the scope of the function, it's defined out of it. What you can do, is pass the value of the checkbox when you call the `checked()` function for the specific row. So, that would be:

```
function checked($value) {
    if (in_array($value, $_SESSION['specificvalue'])) { 
        return "checked"; 
    }
}
```

And the call:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<input id='specificvalue' type='checkbox' ".checked($row['subunit']).
    " name='specificvalue[]'  value='". $row['specificvalue'] . "'>" .
    $row['longvalue']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: thanks. i already had two while loops with if, but this is more neat.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it with `$row['subunit']` you will be unable to do that with in functions scope as $row is not accessible inside the function `checked()`.

To be able to do this you need to define the value of `$row['subunit']` in the function as argument. Like this:

```
function checked($valueToSearch)
{
    if (in_array($valueToSearch, $_SESSION['specificvalue'])) 
        return "checked";
}
```

And, you have to pass it from the loop everytime you call the check.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    echo "<input id='specificvalue' type='checkbox' ".checked($row['subunit'])." name='specificvalue[]'  value='". $row['specificvalue'] . "'>" .$row['longvalue']."<br>";
};
```

Hope it would help.